# javascript function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined

I am sure I am doing this all kinds of wrong, but I have the following function returning 'undefined' in the console even though it can console.log() the wanted values from the same place in the function as commented in the code.

```
var tags = [4, 5];
console.log(getTagNames(tags)); // 'undefined'

function getTagNames(tagArray) {  

    $.getJSON('js/tags.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in tagArray) {
            tagArray[i] = tagArray[i].toString();
            var val = tagArray[i];

            for (var t in data) {
                var tag = data[t];
                var tagName = tag.alias;
                var tagId = tag.id;
                if (val === tagId) {
                    tagArray[i] = tagName;
                }
            };
        }
        console.log(tagArray); // output ["foo", "bar"] 
        return tagArray;
    });
}
```

The other odd thing is that, after running this code in the browser, I can type "tags" into the browser console and it gives me the correct result `["foo", "bar"]`. However when I try using the tags variable (i.e.: text value for an element and such), it doesn't work...
What Gives? JavaScript isn't my first language so I am a little confused of exactly how it behaves. I just don't understand.

I have read almost all of the "Questions that may already have my answer", but the answers supplied where those that I couldn't figure out how to apply to my function.

**NOTE:**

1. The JSON is from the Joomla(3.1) tags table.
2. I am able to retrieve the data.
3. The val === tagId conditional is working correctly.
4. I like popcorn.

Comment: `getTagNames` **doesn't have** a `return` statement. The only function with a `return` statement in your question is the anonymous function you pass to `getJSON`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `getJSON` calls your callback function asynchronously.

If you need the function `getTagNames` and call it many places in your code you could make changes to make it take a callback function itself:

```
function getTagNames(tagArray, cb) {  

    $.getJSON('js/tags.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in tagArray) {
            tagArray[i] = tagArray[i].toString();
            var val = tagArray[i];

            for (var t in data) {
                var tag = data[t];
                var tagName = tag.alias;
                var tagId = tag.id;
                if (val === tagId) {
                    tagArray[i] = tagName;
                }
            };
        }
        console.log(tagArray); // output ["foo", "bar"] 
        cb(tagArray);
    });
}
```

and then make calls to it like this:

```
getTagNames(tags, function(tagArray) {
    // do something with tagArray
});
```

Comment: I think its the "callback" function that I don't get when I need to make calls to the getTagNames function. Like what does the parameter, tagArray represent here. And what would I want to do with it. I guess I am used too php in just returning value.

Comment: tagArray is copied (like most of the code) from your original. So tagArray is getting populated by calling getTagNames. The second parameter you pass is a function that handles the "return value" when the call to getTagNames is "finished".

Answer (score 2):

Statement `return tagArray;` returns result of `success` handler of `getJSON` which, first, does not expect any return value, and second, happens asynchronously - way after your `getTagNames` finished executing.

Comment: That's pretty much the the answer I got from the other questions that I looked over, and I only half understand how it works. However I can't seem to find any reference material that dumbs-it-down for my current comprehension of the whole concept. Still reading over some material so I can hit that "AH HA" moment. Any place anyone can direct me (preferably tutorial based) is greatly appreciated.